# Debug async waterfall AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, aws-lambda

I am writing a lambda for converting images and I am using async.waterfall for it.
I am having a hard time debugging the lambda, since it does not seem to start the second function transform. Can any body help me on debugging. This is actually a pretty basic setup but I don't see why it does not go into the transform function nor throws any errors

```
    async.waterfall([
        function download(next) {
            
            s3.getObject({
                    Bucket: srcBucket,
                    Key: srcKey
                },
                next);
        },
        function transform(response, next) {
            console.log("transform", response);
            sharp(response.Body)
                .webp()
                .toBuffer(next);
        },
        function upload(data, info, next) {
            console.log("upload");
            s3.putObject({
                    Bucket: dstBucket,
                    Key: dstKey,
                    Body: data,
                },
                next);
        }
    ], function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(
                'Unable to convert ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
                ' and upload to ' + dstBucket + '/' + dstKey +
                ' due to an error: ' + err
            );
        } else {
            console.log(
                'Successfully converted ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
                ' and uploaded to ' + dstBucket + '/' + dstKey
            );
        }
        callback(null, "message");
    });
```

Comment: Is the lambda function built using [SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html)?

Comment: yes!!  Does that make a difference ?

Comment: FYI the `getObject` callback receives two parameters: `err` and `data`.

Comment: Does it actually execute the getObject call (I see no logging there)? Do the CloudWatch Logs for this Lambda function show any errors? Did the Lambda function time out (default timeout is 3 seconds which may not be enough to download a large file)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AWS SAM, then you can start the lambda environment locally. Look at the possible options available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-start-lambda.html). Invoking the code locally can help you debug the code.

Comment: I did that before. Its running know, but I don't know where the problem was, I made no code changes ???? Thanks anyway